# Writing Android package name and version number to a json file during ant build

Tags: android, ant

I need to write app's package name and version number to a file named settings.json placed under assets folder during my ant build.

Is there a way to do it? I tried echo command but not able to achieve it.
Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly happened when you tried using the echo command?

Comment: I got it working, I was using the command in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer,

```
<echo file="../DemoApp/assets/settings.json" append="true" force="true">
    {
        "ApplicationID":"${mymanifest.manifest.package}",
        "ApplicationVersion":"${mymanifest.manifest.android:versionName}",
    }
</echo>
```